# python: after a thread run to the end, will it still consume resource (such as memory)

Tags: python, multithreading

I will kick off many threads, and each thread will run a single function will normally completed in server hours. After the function exit, the thread will have isAlive() as false, but will that dead thread still consume memory? if still consume memory, then how to let it release the memory?

Comment: Are you joining the threads?

Comment: There's much more to it than just "will it consume memory", because it might, it might not. Depending on what you're doing in your code there will be a certain amount of garbage collection - and depending on what, where and how your data and handles are used later on, X amount of memory etc will be freed.
I'd suggest you run a profiler and see what memory footprint your threads have. And follow the guidelines on thread handling to be as accurate with your management of threads as possible. Voting to close because it's a very broad question with broad answers.

Comment: @NilsWerner, I didn't join any threads, just kick off the thread and let it run in the background, my expectation is to let it run to the end, then just release everything. Just like run a background shell job, after the it run, I hope it to release all memory.